# Fabricjs update object outside group

Tags: fabricjs

I have complex functionalities which update objects which is relative to one main object. This main object can be selectable, so it can be in group. When i am moving this object inside one group, i am temporary removing this main object update it and re add it. So the code is look like this:

```
groupObject.removeWithUpdate(mainObject);
canvas.add(mainObject);
complexFunction(mainObject);
canvas.remove(mainObject);
groupObject.addWithUpdate(mainObject);
```

This is working nicely. Next problem is to place our main object to the index it has before in the group. Very first thing i tried and it should work is: `mainObject.sendBackwards()` as much times as it has to be, but i see error `Uncaught TypeError: this._findNewLowerIndex is not a function`. Next this is something i build custom, this is working as algorithm, but it fail after `canvas.renderAll()` and what i mean is that object before that algorithm is show, below is the code.

```
for (var i = all-1; i > place; i--) {
    temp = groupObject._objects[i-1];
    groupObject._objects[i-1] = groupObject._objects[i];
    groupObject._objects[i] = temp;
}
canvas.renderAll();
```